# Error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RenderWindow::draw(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'| SFML in C++

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I tried to create a `Button` class and use it with SFML, unfortunately, it produces the error:

> no matching function for call to 'sf::RenderWindow::draw()'|

and a few more.

This is the code:

```
void onclic(){

                    cout << "Clicked";

                }

class Button{

public:

    string ButtonText;

    Color color;

    int sizee;

    int x;

    int y;

    RenderWindow winname;

    void func(){

        cout << "\n";

    }

    void Butt(string ButtonText, Color color, int sizee, int x, int y, function<void()> funcc, RenderWindow winname){

        Text tt;

        tt.setString(ButtonText);

        tt.setColor(color);

        tt.setPosition(x, y);

        tt.setCharacterSize(sizee);

        Event e;

        while (winname.pollEvent(e)) {

            switch (e.type) {
        case Event::MouseButtonPressed:

            funcc();

            }
        }

    }

};

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow sfmlWin;

    sfmlWin.setTitle("Hello!");

    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("Raleway-Regular.ttf")) {

                               while (sfmlWin.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event e;
        while (sfmlWin.pollEvent(e)) {

            switch (e.type) {
            case sf::Event::EventType::Closed:

                using namespace sf;

                Text t;

                t.setCharacterSize(20);

                t.setString("Something");

                sfmlWin.draw(t);

            }
        }

        sfmlWin.clear();
        sfmlWin.draw(t);
        sfmlWin.display();
    }

        return -1;
    }


    sf::Text message("Hello, World!", font);

    while (sfmlWin.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event e;
        while (sfmlWin.pollEvent(e)) {

            switch (e.type) {
            case sf::Event::EventType::Closed:

                using namespace sf;

                Text t;

                t.setString("Something");

                sfmlWin.draw(t);

                Button buttt;

                Color col(0,255,0);

                buttt.Butt("CLICK!", col, 20, 50, 50, onclic, sfmlWin);

                sfmlWin.draw(buttt.Butt);

            }
        }

        if (e.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
{
    if (e.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
    {

        if(e.mouseButton.x >= 20 && e.mouseButton.y >= 20 && e.mouseButton.x <= 40 && e.mouseButton.y <= 40){

            cout << "Pressed.";

        }

    }
}

        sfmlWin.clear();
        sfmlWin.draw(message);
        sfmlWin.display();


    }


    return 0;
}
```

This was the first error in the Build log in Code::Blocks.

> error: use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'.

The very next line was

> In file included from C:...\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:47,                  from E:\something.cpp:4: C:\Users...\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp:44:25: note: 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:  class SFML_GRAPHICS_API RenderWindow : public Window, public RenderTarget                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Yes, but I had used the namespace sf. That's not the error I guess...

Comment: Very sorry. This was the first error in the Build log in Code::Blocks. `error: use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'`.

Comment: The very next line was
`In file included from C:\...\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/Graphics.hpp:47,
                 from E:\something.cpp:4:
C:\Users\...\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit\SFML-2.5.1\include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp:44:25: note: 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class SFML_GRAPHICS_API RenderWindow : public Window, public RenderTarget
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `error: use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'.`

This tells you that you are trying to copy a `sf::RenderWindow` but a `sf::RenderWindow` is not copyable.

In the shown code, this is the offending copy:

```
void Butt(string ButtonText, Color color, int sizee, int x, int y,
          function<void()> funcc, RenderWindow winname)
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Make that a reference instead:

```
void Butt(string ButtonText, Color color, int sizee, int x, int y,
          function<void()> funcc, RenderWindow& winname)
//                                            ^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But now I get another error: `E:\...\something.cpp:154:40: error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RenderWindow::draw(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
                 sfmlWin.draw(buttt.Butt);
                                        ^` Any idea why so?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder You're welcome. Please open a new question for this new issue. I suspect that the `draw` method doesn't have an overload that accepts a `Button`. It could be that `Button` should inherit from a base class in sfml.